# .htaccess rule to use a separate 404 page for subdirectory

Tags: htaccess, 404

I've made a subsite which runs under `example.com/subsite` - ideally from an architecture point of view it would be under a subdomain, but we wanted the links to come back to the main domain.

The sub site has a completely different design, and layout, and has a 404 page that is in keeping with the rest of it.

How can I set the 404 for the `/subsite` subdirectory, without affecting the root domains 404 settings in the `.htaccess` file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Very simple. Just create another .htaccess file in the /subsite directory, and set your `ErrorDocument 404` in it to the subsite's 404 page, ie `ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/subfolder/alternate-404.html`. The .htaccess in the parent folder will still be used for the main document root, and all other subfolders.

Comment: Generally, you shouldn't be using an absolute URL as the document target in the `ErrorDocument` directive as this will result in a 302 external redirect (not a 404). You should be using a root-relative URL-path, eg. `ErrorDocument /subfolder/alternate-404.html`.